# Eclipse Kepler, Hibernate Tools and SQL Server code generation fails can't find database

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools, jboss-tools

I am attempting to use code generation in Hibernate tools but it is failing. It seems to be quoting the database name somehow and I can't figure out why. I really have a lot of tables I need to generate and I don't want to do it by hand... Anyone got an idea?

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error while reading column meta data for `mydb`.dbo.account

Error while reading column meta data for `mydb`.dbo.account
  java.sql.SQLException: Database '`mydb`' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Database '`mydb`' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
    java.sql.SQLException: Database '`mydb`' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

```
Database '`mydb`' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```